# Transpose template parameter pack

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, variadic-templates

I want to pass a row-major argument list to a constexpr constructor and store the data in a column-major array. I have to transpose the template parameter pack from row-major to column-major and the only way I came up with was by using a temporary array like this:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t rows, std::size_t cols = rows>
class Matrix final
{
public:
  std::array<T, cols * rows> m; // column-major matrix

  template <typename ...A>
  constexpr Matrix(const A... args) noexcept:
    m{transpose(std::array<T, rows * cols>{args...}, std::make_index_sequence<rows * cols>{})}
  {}

  template <std::size_t ...i>
  constexpr auto transpose(const std::array<T, cols * rows> a,
                           const std::index_sequence<i...>) noexcept
  {
    return std::array<T, cols * rows>{a[((i % rows) * cols + i / rows)]...};
  }
};
```

I guess there is no other way to access the elements in a parameter-pack out of order, but maybe there is a way to do it without an intermediate array.

Comment: Not sure the syntax or other method you want...

Comment: I am searching for a method that does not create an intermediate array (passed as parameter to transpose) e.g. copying the parameter pack directly to the destination array. That would make the code faster in unoptimized (debug) builds.

Comment: `std::tuple` created with `std::forward_as_tuple` or `std::tie` might replace the intermediate `std::array`.

Comment: Consider taking an initializer list instead of a parameter pack, like `std::vector` does. You can index into `std::initializer_list<T>`

Answer (score 3):

To significantly improve the performance of debug builds without removing features, you'll need to replace `std::array` with a more basic functionless version:

https://quick-bench.com/q/FS2cphByJEWMFMsquI_Yor8ZnyI

The resulting version (ChangedArrayBasic) is ~2.8x faster than the original on Clang 12.0, -O0, libstdc++.

The index operator must not be used since it appears to be largely unoptimizable in practice, instead the internal array needs to be accessed manually.

```cpp
template <class T, size_t N>
struct BasicCustomArray
{
  T d[N];
};

template <typename T, std::size_t rows, std::size_t cols = rows>
class NewMatrixBasic final
{
public:
  using Arr = BasicCustomArray<T, cols * rows>; // <-----------------------------
  Arr m; // column-major matrix

  template <typename ...A>
  constexpr NewMatrixBasic(const A... args) noexcept:
    m{transpose(Arr{args...}, std::make_index_sequence<rows * cols>{})}
  {}

  template <std::size_t ...i>
  constexpr auto transpose(const Arr a,
                           const std::index_sequence<i...>) noexcept
  {
    return Arr{a.d[((i % rows) * cols + i / rows)]...}; // <---------------------
  }
};
```

Comment: Once optimization turned on, there are similar [Demo](https://quick-bench.com/q/19JSFJUdP1H0p8BbpeCbq65lv6k).

Comment: Thank you, I will stick to using this solution. It seems that there is no way to directly copy rows to columns with templates.